# Are macros "provided" in <float.h> (in C89) expected to behave as constant values?

Tags: c, macros, c99, c11, c89

I am writting a small project that has to take in account all versions of Standard C, from C89 to C11, trying to ensure some degree of compatibility across versions. In doing this, I found that the Standard Header `<float.h>` has very different specfications in C89  compared to C99.

In C89, almost all macros in `<float.h>`, except `FLT_RADIX`, are not necessarily constant expressions. However, in C99 all macros in `<float.h>` except `FLT_ROUNDS` are constant expressions (they can be used, for example, in `static` initializers).

My guess is that, even in the ancient C89, the expected behaviour for a given conforming implementation is that all macros in `<float.h>` (except `FLT_ROUNDS`) has to be unmodifiable values along program execution, even when they cannot be considered syntacticly as constant expressions.

On the other hand, C89 Standard document says [(C89 draft, 2.2.4.2)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#2.2.4.2):

> The floating-point model representation is **provided** for all values except FLT_ROUNDS.

Here "all values" refers to the list of macros declared in `<float.h>`.

**MY QUESTION:** What does it mean in C89 the word **provided**? Is it right to interpret that the implementation **provides** values for the macros that are unmodifiable along program execution? Moreover: are they unmodifiable values for the target execution environment?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems like a case where you could write your code as if these are always constant expressions, and if you someday discover a compiler where the code does not compile, worry about it then.  There doesn't seem to be any risk of UB or runtime errors here, only compile-time ones.  And compile-time problems are always going to occur in new portable projects--you just have to find them and fix them for the platforms you build on.

Comment: I don't think that this is the right question to ask yourself. C89 was almost 30 years ago and the C committee has amended it since then, in many parts for this reason: be more precise on what to expect. As for writing code today, if you have a list of compilers that don't even adhere to C99, you should have previsions for them, individually, for cases where you know they break expectations. For the case you mention, I can't imagine any compiler provider, even 30 years ago, being stupid enough to have these expression as function calls or alike.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Thank your by your comments. The book "The  standard C library", by Plaucer, enters in an interesting discussion about this topic, and suggests to make implementations of <float.h> by defining some of its macros as the values of certain union members, previously built by using type-punning and bit patterns. However, it seems like anyway, these values remain unmodifiable along program execution.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Many C89 compilers offer the more useful parts of C99 as extensions, even if they don't support things like variable-length arrays.  As for whether compilers might have some of those values as expressions, I would consider it plausible that some implementers may think it useful to provide run-time options to control floating-point behavior (e.g. a 16-bit implementation might have an option to make "double" ignore the bottom 5 bits of the mantissa so that a "double" multiply would require nine 16x16 multiplies rather than sixteen of them).  What should DBL_DIG do on one of those?